# move data to another view controller, but the 2nd view controller load first before 1st view controller

Tags: ios, swift

i want to make when user login in the login view controller, the email saved and display to slide out menu view controller, but the slide out menu displayed first when build and run. So the variable contains nothing because user haven't login yet in login view controller.

im using this to declare the text in text field is email fill

```
let emailFill:String = self.emailTextfield.text!
```

and use

```
self.labelContainEmail = emailFill
```

the labelContainEmail is a global variable at top

```
var labelContainEmail: String = ""
```

i'm using prepare for segue like this to move data

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "yolo"
    {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! SlideOutMenu
        vc.labelContainEmail2 = labelContainEmail
        print(vc.labelContainEmail2) // this don't print anything, but when i print under `self.labelContainEmail = emailFill` it printed out the email
    }
}
```

in the slideOutMenu.swift, i have this var at top

```
var labelContainEmail2: String = ""
```

and try to change the label text with

```
labelEmail.text = labelContainEmail2
```

in the view did Load

what should i do? please go easy, i'm new to swift

Comment: Can't understand your question! What you want exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using prepare for segue store email in NSUserDefaults

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(labelContainEmail , forKey: "email")  // save user email
```

in the slideOutMenu.swift and try to change the label text with in the view did Load

```
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("email")) == nil
{ 
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("" , forKey: "email")
}
else
{   
   let emailStr = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("email") as! String
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man! You are Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use on the top this line

** Second View

```
class SlideOutMenu: UIViewController {

  var labelContainEmail: String?

    //your code here 
}
```

Where you are going from first view to second view.

**Use First View

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "yolo"
    {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! SlideOutMenu
        vc.labelContainEmail2 = labelContainEmail
        print(vc.labelContainEmail2) // this don't print anything, but when i print under `self.labelContainEmail = emailFill` it printed out the email
    }
}
```

i hope it will help you other wise you can use Model Class also better way for pass data.